# B2B Commerce Lightning - Product Media via REST or Apex

Tags: b2b-commerce

I'm running into something that is causing me headaches and I wanted to validate whether what I found about this topic is correct.

First of all, some background. I'm working for a customer that has a custom backend system, this is an on-prem solution that hosts all of their processes and data. In this system, they have around 20k products that are relevant for the first phase of our B2B Commerce project. For these 20k products, they have around 3 pictures per product that we would need to display in the storefront. These pictures are stored locally.

We are integrating with this backend, and we pull in the Product data from there. One thing that is available from their endpoints are their product pictures. I can access these images in their Base64 form, so in theory I can save them in Salesforce.

Now, what I'm running into is this:

In Salesforce B2B Commerce, the standard way of making pictures available is by using Salesforce CMS. Salesforce CMS uses something called CMS Content. Every Content record gets assigned a Content Key (which is not the same as a Record Id, it's a text identifier)  The way B2B Commerce links CMS Content to a Product is by using ProductMedia. The ProductMedia object is nothing more than a record that stores a Product Id and the Content Key that should be used. That's important to understand, because it means there is no hard link between a CMS Content record and a Product.

So, what this means is that if you want to add Product images to a Product in a B2B Storefront, you need to have CMS Content records that are linked to a Product via the ProductMedia object.

The standard (and largely manual) way of adding images is by either importing them using the Product Import wizard, or by adding the pictures manually via the UI. **As far as I know, there is no way to add Product Media from apex**. One workaround is to create the Content via REST. There's a REST-endpoint available (/connect/cms/contents) but that only works for Enhanced CMS Workspaces, which are in turn incompatible with B2B Commerce Storefronts.

This means that there is no clear way to process the images from the backend in question programmatically if we want to stick to the standard.

Is my understanding correct? Namely, that I can't create Product Media programmatically and that we're going to have to ditch the standard data model for Product Media if we want to integrate this?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with B2B & CMS. I assume that "CMS Workspaces" and "Enhanced CMS Workspaces" are different? If so, do you have a CMS workspace? I'm trying to clarify because the Object Reference documentation on `ProductMedia` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_productmedia.htm) states, "You must have the B2B Commerce license and a CMS workspace to access product media."

Comment: Yup, we have a CMS workspace, that’s not the issue

Comment: I've spun up a scratch org with `B2BCommerce` & `Communities` & sample data (which includes a few Products & Electronic Media Groups (e.g., Product Detail Images, Product List Image). I have no clue if this is correct in general or the correct order, but in Digital Experience I created a CMS Workspace ("Product Images"); created a public CMS Channel ("Public1") & added it to the workspace; uploaded & published an image. Now in the Commerce App in the Media tab of a Product if I click "Add Image" under "Product List Image" (or others), I can select the image I uploaded. Is this correct so far?

Comment: So far, yes! 

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved! 
I am working on something similar where my product media content is coming from external system. @FrederikPardon

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can create `ProductMedia` records via Apex using ConnectApi methods from the `ManagedContent` class (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedContent_static_methods.htm).

---

Here is a very crude Proof of Concept (POC) I just threw together.  There are quite a few Worst Practices I am illustrating in the Apex code; but since this is a POC, and I knew certain records existed in this org, and the purpose is not to create great code but to demonstrate the possibility of using Apex to do what you want, I'm showing it.  It would need to be greatly refined before it is ready for prime time.

##### Setup

###### Org

I spun up a scratch org using this `project-scratch-def.json`:

```json
{
  "orgName": "SFSE B2B CMS",
  "edition": "Developer"
  "hasSampleData": true,
  "features": ["Communities", "B2BCommerce", "OrderManagement", "EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": { 
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
          "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
      },
      "experienceBundleSettings": {
        "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
      },
      "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
      },
      "orderManagementSettings": {
        "enableOrderManagement": true
      },
      "orderSettings": {
        "enableOrders": true,
        "enableEnhancedCommerceOrders": true,
        "enableOptionalPricebook": true,
        "enableNegativeQuantity": true,
        "enableZeroQuantity": true
      },
      "commerceSettings": {
        "commerceEnabled": true
      }
  }
}
```

*Some of that is unnecessary, I'm sure, but I was going with some of what I'm already using for work.*

Here is a sample of the sample data:

| Object | Samples |
| --- | --- |
| Product | GenWatt Diesel 200kW |
|  | GenWatt Diesel 10kW |
| Electronic Media Group | Product Detail Images |
|  | Product List Image |

*These* Electronic Media Group*s can be seen in the "Media" tab when drilled into a Product record.*

###### Content

In the Digital Experience app...

- Created a CMS Workspace called "Product Images"
- Created a public CMS Channel called "Public1"
- Added the channel to the workspace
- Uploaded a couple of images inside the "Product Images" CMS Workspace
- Published the images

###### Control

In the Commerce app, I manually added one of the images to a product by...

- Drilling into the product record
- Clicking on the "Media" tab
- Clicked "Add Image" under the "Product List Image" group
- Selecting one of my published content images

In Developer Console I queried `ProductMedia` in order to see the connections.  It has three required fields:

- `ProductId`: self-explanatory
- `ElectronicMediaId`: `Id` of the content record that essentially is the image
- `ElectronicMediaGroupId`: `Id` of the aforementioned Electronic Media Group

Then there was much weeping and gnashing of teeth - including how to figure out how to get the Developer Name of the `ManagedContentType`.

##### POC Code

```apex
Id idProduct = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Name = 'GenWatt Diesel 10kW' LIMIT 1].Id;
Id idElecMediaGrp = [SELECT Id FROM ElectronicMediaGroup WHERE Name = 'Product List Image' LIMIT 1].Id;
Id idContentItem;

Id idContentChannel;
ConnectApi.ManagedContentChannelCollection col_mcc = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getAllDeliveryChannels(0, 25);
for (ConnectApi.ManagedContentChannel mcc : col_mcc.channels) {
    if (mcc.channelName == 'Public1') {
        idContentChannel = mcc.channelId;
    }
}

ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersionCollection col_mcv = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getAllContent(
    idContentChannel, 
    0, 
    25, 
    'en_US', 
    'cms_image', 
    false, 
    '2022-11-18T00:00:00.000Z', 
    '2022-11-20T00:00:00.000Z'
);
for (ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersion mcv : col_mcv.items) {
    idContentItem = mcv.managedContentId;
}

ProductMedia pm = new ProductMedia(
    ProductId = idProduct,
    ElectronicMediaGroupId = idElecMediaGrp,
    ElectronicMediaId = idContentItem
);
insert pm;
```

##### Result

A new product image now visible in the Commerce UI.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort you have put into this. Sadly, it solves only half of my issue. Creating Product Media is one thing, but it assumes you have the images already as Image Content in a workspace channel. The largest part of what I’m struggling with is exactly that: creating content programmatically…

Comment: Oops. I guess I misunderstood your statement, "As far as I know, there is no way to add Product Media from [A]pex."

Comment: Don’t get me wrong! What you explained was really helpful!